# Cryptic AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'setsockopt' error message

Tags: python, docker, nameko

I am trying to deploy a dockerized python (**nameko**) application.

Everything works as expected to the point where I am trying to access one of the modules via `GET` method. There I receive a very cryptic error:

```
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/wsgi.py", line 347,
in setup conn.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_QUICKACK, True)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'setsockopt'
```

I know for a fact that my code is not the problem because it is already up and running on a staging machine with no problems (at least of that kind).

The Dockerfile I am using looks like this (and does work mind you!):

```
FROM python:3.5

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["./run.sh"]

RUN adduser --uid 1000 --disabled-password --gecos '' --home /home/devuser devuser

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    libxml2-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxslt1-dev \
    netcat && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY . /app

RUN chown devuser.devuser -R .
USER devuser
```

---

I did nothing different from my staging machine so I do wonder...

Comment: @snakecharmerb Not in my part of the code...

Comment: @snakecharmerb Spot on!! I updated nameko version to 2.8.3 and it worked. (I am willing to accept this if you make it into an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a symptom of a [bug in nameko](https://github.com/nameko/nameko/issues/485), caused by a change in the [eventlet library](https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/commit/7f53465578543156e7251e243c0636e087a8445f).

The solution is to upgrade to nameko 2.8.3, which pins the version of eventlet to be installed to the range 0.16.1 - 0.22.0.